# Fxcop error with return code '2048'

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop

Caused by: org.sonar.dotnet.tools.fxcop.FxCopException: FxCop execution failed with return code '2048'. Check FxCop documentation for more information.
    at org.sonar.dotnet.tools.fxcop.FxCopRunner.execute(FxCopRunner.java:86)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.fxcop.FxCopSensor.launchFxCop(FxCopSensor.java:214)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.fxcop.FxCopSensor.analyse(FxCopSensor.java:169)

Please find the attached log for the error.

Softwares used:
Sonarqube-3.3.1
Maven-3.0.4
Fxcop-12.0

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of both SonarQube and of the SonarQube C# plugin - they both are no longer supported.

The current recommended and supported way of analyzing .NET projects is through the [MSBuild SonarQube Runner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/OA5R).

You won't get help on such old versions of the SonarQube server and SonarQube C# plugin: Please upgrade.